# Data factory cost reducing

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, database-administration, azure-data-factory

How to reduce the costs of azure data factory (we have pipelines for data movement between tables, and triggers, datasets, alerts) ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/) helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

> How to reduce the costs of azure data factory (we have pipelines for data movement between tables, and triggers, datasets, alerts) ?

Before reducing costs, we need to monitor what are the costs to avoid unnecessary costs.

We could:

- First, at the beginning of the ETL project, you conduct proof of
  concept and use a combination of per-pipeline consumption and pricing
  calculator to estimate costs.
- After you have deployed your pipelines to production, you use the
  cost management features to set budgets and monitor costs. You can
  also review the forecasted costs and identify spending trends.
- In addition, you can view per-pipeline consumption and per-activity
  consumption information to understand which pipelines and which
  activities are costliest and identify candidates for cost reduction.

Please refer the document [Plan and manage costs for Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/plan-manage-costs) for some more details.

In addition, we could save costs from running ADF pipelines using Triggers.

Check [this thread](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/save-costs-with-azure-data-factory) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using many copy activities to move data then the under settings tab you can change the default [Data Integration Unit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#data-integration-units) to be 2. The default is 4. This can make a big difference if you have many copy activities.
This will reduce the performance of the copy activity however.

[image: Copy activity].